# In OpenCV4Android, can I remove a few particular pixels from a Mat?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, mat, android

For example, let's say I want to remove the pixel located at `(50, 50)` from a Mat. Can I remove it?

***Some Context:***

I have a `Mat` containing a contour. What I am trying to do is to iterate through each pixel in the `Mat` and **I'd like to remove each pixel which is not located inside the contour, so that I am only left with the part of the `Mat` which lies inside the contour.** Is that possible?

So I am doing

```
for (int firstCoordinate = 0; firstCoordinate < hsvMat.rows(); firstCoordinate++) {//This and nested for are used to iterate through the Mat
    for (int secondCoordinate = 0; secondCoordinate < hsvMat.cols(); secondCoordinate++) {
        if (Imgproc.pointPolygonTest(contour, new Point(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate), false) < 0) {//If this point is outside the contour. 
            //***HERE:I want to remove this pixel. 
           //****SOMETHING LIKE:
           //***hsvMat.get(firstCoordinate,secondCoordinate).remove();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the initial RGBA frame captured:

[image]

*Please keep in mind that the circles which appear blue are actually red (the RGB, BGR issue).*

By doing `Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaFrame, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);`, following is the HSV image.

[image]

Then by doing `Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(0, 50, 40), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), maskedImage);`, and then `Imgproc.dilate(maskedImage, dilatedMat, new Mat());`, we get

[image]
[image]

Then by doing

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(dilatedMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        // \/ We will use only the largest contour. Other contours (any other possible blobs of this color range) will be ignored.
        MatOfPoint largestContour = contours.get(0);
        double largestContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(largestContour);
        for (int i = 1; i < contours.size(); ++i) {// NB Notice the prefix increment.
            MatOfPoint currentContour = contours.get(i);
            double currentContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(currentContour);
            if (currentContourArea > largestContourArea) {
                largestContourArea = currentContourArea;
                largestContour = currentContour;
            }
        }
Rect detectedBlobRoi = Imgproc.boundingRect(largestContour);
Mat detectedBlobRgba = rgbaFrame.submat(detectedBlobRoi);
```

we get

[image]

then by doing `Imgproc.cvtColor(detectedBlobRgba, detectedBlobHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);`, we get

[image]

**And then when I do**

```
//CALCULATING THE AVERAGE COLOR OF THE DETECTED BLOB
int pixelsRemoved = 0;
for (int firstCoordinate = 0; firstCoordinate < detectedBlobHsv.rows(); firstCoordinate++) {
    for (int secondCoordinate = 0; secondCoordinate < detectedBlobHsv.cols(); secondCoordinate++) {
        if (Imgproc.pointPolygonTest(largestContour2f,new Point(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate),false) == -1) {
            pixelsRemoved++;
            detectedBlobHsv.put(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate, new double[]{0,0,0});
        }
    }
}
```

**And it goes wrong. This is what I get when I write the `detectedBlobHsv` to sdcard (ONLY a single reddish vertical line on the left edge =/ )**

[image]

Comment: the short answer is : no, you can't actually **remove** pixels from an image. what you **can** do (and what i guess, you want), is **change their values** . have a look at how to use masks in opencv

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Transparent pixels? Pixels that won't be used for computation of some information? Save memory? Something else? Depending on the application, one more of those things can be achieved...

Comment: @Micka "Pixels that won't be used for computation of some information?" - this! I need to calculate the average HSV color of the `Mat` region inside the contour. This snippet works for the entire `Mat` (but I need to do that for the region inside the contour only): `Scalar detectedBlobHsvColor = new Scalar(255); detectedBlobHsvColor = Core.sumElems(detectedBlobHsv); int pointCount = detectedBlobHsv.width() * detectedBlobHsv.height(); for (int i = 0; i < detectedBlobHsvColor.val.length; i++) {  detectedBlobHsvColor.val[i] /= pointCount; } `

Comment: This is typically done by using masks. But unfortunately, Core.sumElems does not support a mask!

Comment: @Micka What I was previously trying to do was to create a masked Mat, and then copy it to an empty Mat (something like they have done [here](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/5) in C++) using `Imgproc.copyTo()`, but was getting some cv exception. But if I succeed in copying a masked image (obtained as a result of an `inRange()` operation to find a colored blob) to an empty Mat, and then compute the average HSV color of that new Mat, do you think that is the right way to go about it?

Comment: what you can do: set h(sv) value to 0 (00) for each removed point. Then sum of all elements isnt changed by them. for computing the average you must now divide by n-m where n is total image size and m is the number of removed pixels!

Comment: @Micka Looks like this should work. I am going to check.

Comment: @Micka And I got unexpected results. Posted an edit in the question,

Comment: can you try new Scalar (0,0,0) instead of new double []{0,0,0}?

Comment: @Micka `Mat.put()` only takes a `double` type array as the third argument. What difference do you think it would make?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with openCV android/java API. Can you try to draw the polygon?

Comment: @Micka Actually I can't anticipate what shape the colored blob will be. I'll really appreciate if you can tell how would you go about it in C++. I'll try to carry out those steps using the Java API.